# aws documentation for DMS CDC is confusing

Tags: amazon-rds, master-slave-replication, postgresql-11, amazon-dms

I am following this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.Security to enable CDC using logical replication.

I have pglogical extension installed and added under "shared_preload_libraries" parameter. Replication slot created fine -   `SELECT * FROM pg_create_logical_replication_slot('test_slot', 'pglogical');`

but why do i get this error when creating replication set as exactly mentioned in the document?

```
select pglogical.create_replication_set('test_slot', false, true, true, false);
ERROR:  current database is not configured as pglogical node
HINT:  create pglogical node first
```

However, Creating pglogical node step is ONLY covered under a different topic of "Using native CDC..." in the same URL - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html#CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.v10

Can someone please explain the right steps on how to enable logical replication via AWS DMS CDC?

is native cdc different than DMS CDC?